# Apache Health Check timeout

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

mod_proxy_hcheck appears to be lacking a timeout setting for the health checks.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html

I have tested the mod_proxy module timeout and connectiontimeout settings on the proxy balancermember config.  This does not affect the mod_proxy_hcheck health checks.

Are there any ways to configure a timeout for health checks?

Apache version:  Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Comment: good question, I am going to try and find out because I'm seeing the same as you do.